# All sites give Error 500 under Sharepoint Foundation (SP2010)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've just installed Sharepoint Foundatuion on my W2008 64bit server and got it up and running as far as being able to access the Central Admin etc just fine.

I did have to disable 32 bit apps in the application pools for all the SP sites and also, following a tip on here, add a config option for bitness64 as a prerequisite for the services.

However whenever I try to access the "Sharepoint - 80" site itself (or another site collection I created in the admin tool), I am getting an unhelpful 500 error. The log doesn't add anything - I can't find anything to give me a clue as to what it's complaining about.

The server is a hosted VPS and all services like SQL are running locally (and are OK).

Any ideas where I look next?

M

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an incorrect specification of the dependencies for the Sharepoint14Module in applicationHost.config

In order to locate the issue I enabled Failed Request Tracing on the server and examined the logs that get output as a result. The preconditions for the module were incorrectly specified (appPool1,bitness64;appPool2,bitness64 instead of appPool1;appPool2,bitness64). Fixing this the sites sprung in to life :)

M